# Auto File SharePoint Incoming Email

Tags: email

I have a request to setup a doc lib to capture all emails for a particular project and file it in a particular folder within the library.  Here's the a quick run thru:

1. I have a doc lib called BCDL with the incoming email option enabled. The email address for the doc lib is bcdl@mydomain.com.
2. The user will, in advance, manually create folders with naming convention of "Proj-XXXXX" where XXXXX is the project number
3. All emails (with or without attachment) going to bcdl@mydomain.com will be forwardedto the BCDL library.  The subject of the email will include the "Proj-XXXXX" text in it.  Note, the  position of this text can vary is it is a response to an email.
4. After the email arrived, a workflow or task of some sort needs to parse the subject
   and look for the "Proj-XXXXX" and move that email to the "Prox-XXXXX" folder which was pre created in step 2.

In summary, I want to setup a Doc Lib where all incoming email will be filed to the respective "Proj-XXXXX" folder parsed in the subject line.

Not sure where to start.  I have look at the doc lib, one of the issues I am seeing is that email to a doc lib MUST contain an attachment or it will not accept it.  A custom list does not have incoming email option.

**Update 20/11 after answer and comments:**

The problem with grouping is that I can't apply permission to it. Someone would have to apply the permission to each entry. With folder, the user would apply the permission when the folder was first created.

Answer (score 3):

email to a document library MUST have an attachment? Don't think that's true.

[image: Screenshot]

Check out the screenshot above (it's a bit small, sorry). Ensure you have set the "Save Original Email" set to true.

Let's assume for now that would fix it, you have answered a large part of your question already. I would implement an event receiver to handle the parsing of the email + moving the file.

Comment: Thanks Jaap.  I was hoping I don't need to go thru the programming route... obviously I am not a developer.  Wonder if there's JQuery or Sharepoint Designer solution for this.

Comment: A SharePoint Desginer workflow would be nice to use, but I don't think you can parse out the Subject line.  You can see if something is contained there, but not actually parse it.

Comment: What I did was I added a calculated column (called ExtractProj) to parse/extract the "Proj-xxxxx" from the subject and that part works. SPD sees this calculated column.  What I need now is a way to copy or move the document to a the pre-created "Proj-xxxxx" folder.  

Why Microsoft don't extend the option to folders is beyond me.

Comment: Jaap's suggestion and the column you've created is the only possible solution I think. Presumably you are grouping by that column to create "faux folders".

Comment: Yeah, grouping by your calculcated column sounds like a really good idea (if your client is willing to be flexible on the requirements)

Comment: The problem I have with grouping is that I can't apply permission to the entire group... need to do one at at time.  With folder,I can apply permission to the folder easily and that it.

Comment: what about setting up several document libraries, each with their own email address and security settings. Then have a central email address where documents get sent to, and do some clever email rerouting based on the subject contents within exchange (I am assuming exchange can do this - correct me if I'm wrong).